redis.exceptions.ResponseError: unknown command 'JSON.SET' with redis-py
No matter what I try, I keep getting this error message.
import redis

r = redis.Redis(host='127.0.0.1', port=6379)
r.ping() # -> True


r.json().set('test', '.', '{"foo": "bar"}')
# -> redis.exceptions.ResponseError: unknown command 'JSON.SET', with args beginning with: 'test' '.' '{"foo":"bar"}'


Code based on redis-py example
redis-py version: 5.0.7 (latest)
Docker image:
docker run -d --name redis-stack -p 6379:6379 redis/redis-stack:latest

Redis JSON module is enabled (redis-stack container)
docker-cli info modules:
module:name=RedisCompat,ver=1,api=1,filters=0,usedby=[],using=[],options=[]
module:name=search,ver=20814,api=1,filters=0,usedby=[],using=[ReJSON],options=[handle-io-errors]
module:name=timeseries,ver=11012,api=1,filters=0,usedby=[],using=[],options=[]
module:name=redisgears_2,ver=20023,api=1,filters=0,usedby=[],using=[],options=[]
module:name=ReJSON,ver=20610,api=1,filters=0,usedby=[search],using=[],options=[handle-io-errors]
module:name=bf,ver=20612,api=1,filters=0,usedby=[],using=[],options=[]

Setting via CLI is working:
127.0.0.1:6379> JSON.SET 'test' . '{"hello":"world"}'

Actually none of the commands work: JSON.SET, JSON.GET, FT.CREATE ....
Very strange...
Does anyone have any idea why this is not working?

Are you you you don't have additional Redis servers running? It seems likely that you are connected to another instance.

@LiorKogan 'docker ps' lists only this Redis image, also, as mentioned, with docker-cli using same host/port everything works as expected

I can reproduce the error on a Redis server (without modules). On a Redis Stack Server everything works fine. Review the instance running on the port used by the script.
I get this on the simple Redis Server.
  File "/Users/mortensi/venvs/ps/lib/python3.9/site-packages/redis/connection.py", line 536, in read_response
    raise response
redis.exceptions.ResponseError: unknown command 'JSON.SET', with args beginning with: 'test' '.' '"{\"foo\": \"bar\"}"'


After several attempts, I got it to work. Won't call it a solution, but a workaround. In fact, the previous instance was a simple Redis without any additional module. Simply deleting an image and starting a new image on the same port doesn't really seem to work. After new port mapping, everything works as expected.
Running the container on new port solves the problem.
docker run -d --name redis-stack -p 6389:6379 redis/redis-stack:latest

^ Changed local port to 6389
However, I have no idea why everything worked as expected with redis-cli, but not with redis-py. Deleting of __pycache__ doesn't help.
I hope this will help someone.
